# How to customize a standard Office Ribbon Control?

Tags: excel, vsto, office-addins, ribbonx

i am developing an Excel VSTO Add-in for Excel 2016 and later versions, how can i customize a standard Control, is there a Way to use it as a Template for a Custom Control ?

for Example i want to change the editBox apperance from this:

[image]

to this (i used windows forms just for demonstration purposes !)

[image]

is this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to customize the controls provided by the Ribbon XML namespace or add custom controls to the Office Ribbon. It is simply not supported.

What is possible is to add WinForms controls to a Custom Task Pane. With VSTO they can also be added to the document surface.

For the requirement shown in the question you could try preceding the edit box control with a `labelControl`, positioned between two large buttons. You probably can't get it centered vertically, but the general effect should be closer.